# sIFR 3: Background Transparent?

Tags: javascript, css, flash, sifr

i'm working on using sIRF for the first time as a way to implement specific typography on a website. it's all working nicely but i have one problem, i want the background to be transparent. i've looked thru the sIRF wiki and im not sure if this is something that is possible..

does anyone know of a way to do this?

i have a test page here > http://www.bevelite.com.au/test

sIRF documentation here > http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lately I use Facelift as I find it a little easier to work with than sIFR... but I believe to make the background transparent you do something like this:

```
sIFR.replace(yourtypeface, {
      selector: 'h2.cpost-title',
      wmode: 'transparent'
});
```

Comment: thanks zac that's exactly what i was looking for!

facelift looks good also, but i'll stick with sIFR for now as i'd like to keep the text as text and not an image.